# PHP function passed by reference could not display the entire element of array

Tags: php, arrays

I don't think if my code was correct but i'd reviewed PHP manual in function passe by reference. I don't think if i have missed something but can't figure it out..

my function is here:

```
public function display_victims(&$vName, &$vAddr, &$vAge, &$vGender){
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($vName); $i++) 
                    {
                        echo $vName[$i].'|'.$vAddr[$i].'|'.$vAge[$i].'|'.$vGender[$i];
                        return true;
        }
 }
```

my form was in the other file I send the form in this file named save_data.php
here is the code:

```
$csppoAdmin = new CsppoAdmin();

 if ($_REQUEST['save']=='rc'){

      extract($_REQUEST);

     $post = $csppoAdmin->report_crime($vName, $vAddr, $vAge, $vGender)

     echo $post;

 }
```

when I run it the output was only one element of the array or one row only.

Comment: What is `report_crime()` ? Cause you've only supplied the code for `display_victims()` ?

Comment: What is in $_REQUEST?

Comment: No that is display_victims() I pasted the wrong function.. but in my work it was display_victims()

Comment: @progsource - the value of vName, vAddr, vAge and vGender

Comment: I wanted to know if there is really all data which you need in the variables in request ;)

Comment: @progsource  - From the input type text named vName[], vAddr[], vAge[] and vGender[]. .The user may add input type text and it will add the element of each array.

Comment: yes there is all data i need..

Comment: You don't need to pass the variables by reference since you are not modifying them in the function. If there is only one item shown, then there is also only one item in your request. You might want to add the HTML code of the form you are submitting.